Why doesn't marking parameters in multiple fixtures work?
pytest 8.3.3
I have 2 fixtures, both parametrized with params=...:
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=["opt1_notsmoke", "opt1_smoke"])
def opt1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=["opt2_notsmoke", "opt2_smoke"])
def opt2(request):
    return request.param

def test_1(opt1, opt2):
    print(opt1)
    print(opt2)

pytest pt.py --collect-only collects the right pairs:
<Module pt.py>
    <Function test_1[opt1_notsmoke-opt2_notsmoke]>
    <Function test_1[opt1_notsmoke-opt2_smoke]>
    <Function test_1[opt1_smoke-opt2_notsmoke]>
    <Function test_1[opt1_smoke-opt2_smoke]>

However, when I try to mark a single parameter in both fixtures, the results don't seem quite right:
@pytest.fixture(params=["opt1_notsmoke", pytest.param("opt1_smoke", marks=pytest.mark.smoke)])
def opt1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=["opt2_notsmoke", pytest.param("opt2_smoke", marks=pytest.mark.smoke)])
def opt2(request):
    return request.param

pytest pt.py --collect-only -m smoke collected:
<Module pt.py>
    <Function test_1[opt1_notsmoke-opt2_smoke]>
    <Function test_1[opt1_smoke-opt2_notsmoke]>
    <Function test_1[opt1_smoke-opt2_smoke]>

I think the nodes with *notsmoke in them shouldn't be collected at all. Meanwhile, marking parameter in a single fixture works fine, no matter which one I choose. It collects the right nodes:
@pytest.fixture(params=["opt1_notsmoke", pytest.param("opt1_smoke", marks=pytest.mark.smoke)])
def opt1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=["opt2_without_mark"])
def opt2(request):
    return request.param

opt1-notsmoke not collected as expected:
<Module pt.py>
    <Function test_1[opt1_smoke-opt2_without_mark]>

Am I unaware of some underlying pytest logic? Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!
I tried to mark parameters inside parametrized fixtures, but it only works when I do it in a single fixture.

In case someone's interested, this is by design. Elaborated here:
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/12909

Works as intended, parameters are a product, so we get ⁴ tests
1 non marked
2 once marked
1 twice

